# Add distance into coordinate

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, coordinates, latitude-longitude

So i have coordinate (A) with x longitude and y latitude. What i want is create new coordinate (B) where distance (meter) beetween both of coordinate and direction (0 - 360) based on user input. What formula to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

for algorithm [see](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00190-012-0578-z) direct and inverse geodesic
problems for implementation [see](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/)